# How to instantiate an object from a class in Java that is located in another file

Tags: java, oop

Do they have to be in the "package", or is it fine as long as they are both in the "src" directory.

For context, I'm using VSCode with the Java extension enabled. It automatically sets up the    project directory to look like this:

```
newproject.java (directory name)
└── bin
└── src
 └── App.java
```

Should I be doing this?

```
   newproject.java (directory name)
   └── bin
   └── src
    └── packager
      └── App.java
```

and then specify the package in all java files, for example:

```
   package packager
   public class App { 
        // more code
   }
```

```
   package packager
   public class TheOtherClass { 
        // more code
   }
```

Or will they be fine as long as they are under src? Or am I totally missing the point?

Right now I'm getting `The declared package "packager" does not match the expected package` error in both files.

Comment: Code in the "unnamed package" can use any other code visible to it (including other classes in the unnamed package). But code in named packages have no way to import classes in the unnamed package. Regardless, it's good practice to use packages in all but the most trivial of applications. To use a class in another source file, import it if the two classes are not in the same package, and then just use it like normal (e.g., `var instance = new TheOtherClass();`).

Comment: As for the "_The declared package "packager" does not match the expected package_" error, my guess is that VS Code doesn't have `src` setup as the root source directory (not sure why if it creates that directory for you).

Comment: Don't think file/directory, think class, classpath